# WPF dependency property return value

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I'm fairly new to WPF.

Suppose I defined an int dependency property. The purpose of the DP is to return the value+1 (see code).
In .Net 2.0 I would have written:

```
private int _myValue = 0;
    public int MyValue
    {
        get { return _myValue + 1; }
        set { _myValue = value; }
    }
```

How would you declare a DP that achieves similar behavior?

---

The Coercion that was offered works only for the Set operation. I would like to modify the Get result.

Comment: There's no way to filter a "get" result for a dependency property value. The coercion does exactly what you ask if you consider it from outside of the object, only in another way. You may try however, to store a pre-coerced value locally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would achieve it indirectly like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(int), typeof(OwnerClass),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, null, new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceValue)));

public int Value
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}

private static object CoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object value)
{
    return (int) value + 1;
}
```

Check this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9aca3e19-f9cd-47f4-89c2-39764f0b8274) for an explanation about coercion.